# How can i mammping the result to an special bean, by spring data jpa

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User,Integer>{

    @Query(value="select id as id ,name as name from user where id=:id",native =true)
    UserVO getBeanByID(@param("id")int ID);
}
```

but it throw a exception , "object[] cant convert to UserVO".

Is there a an annotation or other ways to return it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `native` query for retrieving the `UserVO` bean, rather you can simply use the below method:

```
public UserVO findById(int id);
```

Spring data will implement this method if you have got the `id` variable (mapped to a column in the database table) in your `UserVO` bean.

Comment: it doesn't work,and a new exception is:          org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [cn.jxt.game.dao.jpa.entity.User] to type [cn.jxt.game.common.dto.UserBean]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Spring Projections`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections).

Simply define an interface with the **getters** of the column that you want to retrieve.

```
interface UserVO{  

    String getId(); 
    String getName();  

}
```

Now you can use this `UserVO` in your repository methods like

```
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User,Integer>{

    UserVO findById(int ID); //This will give you UserVO object with only the defined fields(id, name)

}
```

**PS:** I have not tested this but it should work.

Comment: @hanchao did it help?

Comment: i have resolved it in another way,like hibernate, sqlquery~ ths very much